# How to mock the HttpSessionStateBase with NSubstitute

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing, session, moq, nsubstitute

In Moq I can set up a session variable like this (vb.NET code):

```
Dim httpContext As Mock(Of HttpContextBase) = New Mock(Of HttpContextBase)()
Dim httpRequest As Mock(Of HttpRequestBase) = New Mock(Of HttpRequestBase)()
Dim httpResponse As Mock(Of HttpResponseBase) = New Mock(Of HttpResponseBase)()
Dim httpSession As Mock(Of HttpSessionStateBase) = New Mock(Of HttpSessionStateBase)()
**httpSession.Setup(Function(s) s("RoleId")).Returns(1008)**
...
```

How can I do it with NSubstitute?

I have tried these but not working:

```
HttpSession.Item("RoleId").Returns(1008) 'but got the error NullReferenceExpection.

httpContext.Session("RoleId").Returns(1008) 'but got the same error
```

Update:
Tried Nkosi's C# example, it worked.   However when converting it into vb.NET like this:

```
<Fact>
Public Sub Session_Should_Have_Item()
Dim httpContext = Substitute.[For](Of HttpContextBase)()
Dim expected = 1008
httpContext.Session("RoleId").Returns(expected)
Dim actual = httpContext.Session("RoleId")
actual.Should().Be(expected)
End Sub
```

the run time error is thrown at the line as I previously mentioned:

```
enter code here`httpContext.Session("RoleId").Returns(expected)
```

It seems to me that NSubstitute doesn't support vb.net very well -- it has trouble to parse the parenthesis.  Can anybody confirm that is the issue?

Comment: the error message is:  An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object variable or With block variable not set.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
Dim httpContext As HttpContextBase = Substitute.For(Of HttpContextBase)()
Dim httpSession As HttpSessionStateBase = Substitute.For(Of HttpSessionStateBase)()

httpSession("RoleId").Returns(1008)

httpContext.Session.Returns(httpSession)
```

Which references the examples from documentation.

While [Auto and recursive mocks](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/auto-and-recursive-mocks/) should work in this case, you can take the verbose approach demonstrated above

Though in c#, the following does work when using NSubstitute with recursive mocks

```cs
[Fact]
public void Session_Should_Have_Item() {
    //Arrange
    var httpContext = Substitute.For<HttpContextBase>();
    var expected = 1008;
    httpContext.Session["RoleId"].Returns(expected);

    //Act
    var actual = httpContext.Session["RoleId"];

    //Assert
    actual.Should().Be(expected);
}
```

Comment: I tried the statement "httpSession("RoleId").Returns(1008)"  but got the same error I mentioned previously.  Will study the link you provided and try the examples there.

Comment: I have tried your C# code and it is working.  However when I converted it into vb.net code like this:       <Fact>
Public Sub Session_Should_Have_Item()
    Dim httpContext = Substitute.[For](Of HttpContextBase)()
    Dim expected = 1008
    httpContext.Session("RoleId").Returns(expected)
    Dim actual = httpContext.Session("RoleId")
    actual.Should().Be(expected)
End Sub  the error goes to the line:  httpContext.Session("RoleId").Returns(expected)